# HP-UX: Python error on os.uname() function

Tags: python, hp-ux

Has anyone ever seen the Python `os.uname()` function fail on HP-UX?

```
> python -c "import os; print os.uname()" 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
OSError: [Errno 72] Value too large to be stored in data type
```

I've read posts on the hp.com forums which mentioned to check the `uname_eoverflow` kernel parameter, but it is already set to `1`.

```
> kctune | grep uname 
uname_eoverflow         1 Default Immed
```

Comment: What if you set it to 0 : `kctune uname_eoverflow=0` ?